# Sql query bracket - replacing all text with a single character

Tags: sql-server

I have a  situation where i need to replace the entire text and the square bracket with a single charecter inside stored procedure.
( Iam using Sql Server 2012).

Eg:->

Let us consider that i have a text  **san[123456dd]text**

i just wanted to replace all the text inside the square bracket and square bracket itself with another charecter say 'X'

Here, My end result should be **sanXtext**.

Could anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Did you google this? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: google for "SQL REPLACE"

Comment: do you have to consider nested [], or If the complete text is not in single line inside the procedure so that search across the multiple lines? if yes then you also want to look at CHARINDEX function.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(1000) = 'san[123456dd]text'

SELECT LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX('[', @String)-1) +'X' +
       RIGHT(@String, CHARINDEX(']', REVERSE(@String))-1)

Result: sanXtext
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(col,SUBSTRING(col, (CHARINDEX('[',col)), CHARINDEX(']',col) - 
          (CHARINDEX('[', col)) + Len(']')),'x')
  FROM tableName
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/552ab/1)