# MySQL: Search for words that may have interferring characters inbetween

Tags: mysql

I store lyrics of songs and also allow chords to be added by putting them between square brackets (e.g: `[Dm7]`). Here's an example of lyrics stored in my database:

```
Left my fear [Dm7]by the side of the [B]road
Hear You[C] speak won't let[E] go
Fall to my knees
...
```

What I want to do is search for lyrics in songs. For example I might want to search for the lyrics `fear by the side` . The problem is the `[Dm7]` in my example above does not allow a simple `LIKE` search.

Is it possible to do a search (REGEX?) that excludes text such as `[Dm7]` from a query? If so how? Please note that the chords between the square brackets can vary.

Comment: You could split it on the words and add a wildcard between them. A replace that start on [ and ends on ] would be an even better solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917673/sql-query-bracket-replacing-all-text-with-a-single-character  this question might help

Comment: be lazy. store two copies of the lyrics - one with the chords, one without

Comment: @pala_ I'm trying to avoid being lazy but I have considered it if there's no simple way.

Comment: Since `LIKE` queries have pretty poor performance in most cases you probably want to look at a fulltext search solution instead, I would recommend giving ElasticSearch a try instead. It can easily solve problems like these and it outperforms MySQL easily when doing text search.

Comment: @SvenB <a href="https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace">Replace</a> could work. `REPLACE(sa.arrangement_lyrics, '[Dm7]', '') RLIKE 'fear by the side'`. Is it possible to do this with REGEX?

Comment: anything that mangles the string every time you search it is going to perform like rubbish. then again, anything that searches for words anywhere in the string is going to perform like rubbish. fulltext might be your best bet

Comment: @pala why the regex is only preformed once right ?.

Comment: @SvenB yes but it renders any indexing useless - so does searching for '%.... %' tho

Comment: @pala i would prefer editing the query string on the client side but the language hes working with is limited to the sql database.

Comment: @SvenB Got it working! That first link you gave helped but had to change it up a bit.

Comment: @BenSinclair how is the performance? as pala said it might be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to consider a `fulltext` index, and then use `match() against()` in your where clause. Example:

```
create fulltext index ftx on songs(lyrics);

select *
  from songs
    where match(lyrics) against('fear by the side');
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/164c8/4)

The matching is a little fuzzy, and you can't use the boolean mode matching because the chords don't have whitespace on both sides, but the normal mode should be sufficient.

The 'fuzziness' of the match can be used to provide a match ranking - works best on english language, which this seems to be. For example:

```
select match(lyrics) against('fear by the side') rank, 
       lyrics from songs
  where match(lyrics) against('fear by the side') 
  order by match(lyrics) against('fear by the side') desc;
```

Would sort the results by best match, and also return the matching rank.

[updated demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d18e7/5)

The `fulltext` index also has a boolean mode, which as the same suggests, can be used to force the results to include or exclude certain words like so:

`match(column) against('+word -otherword' in boolean mode)` would return all rows for which `column` contains `word` but does not have `otherword`.

your fulltext index can also be multi column, if you desire.

Comment: @pala_ Hmm only problem I face here is it's not a literal match. Because it's FULL TEXT it seems to pick up other lyrics that have those words but not all of them... Not sure if there's a way to make it literal or if I'll have to use my other code.

Comment: @BenSinclair correct - it's fuzzy, but it also has a fuzziness ranking. I would think this would be appropriate for a lyrics search, considering how often one or two words are misheard, or misspelt. I actually just finished adding info about how to use it like that

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SvenB and his suggestion of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917673/sql-query-bracket-replacing-all-text-with-a-single-character), this was my answer.

```
REPLACE(col, SUBSTRING(col, (LOCATE('[', col)), LOCATE(']', col) - (LOCATE('[',  col)) + 1), '') LIKE '%fear by the side%'
```

It's a bit messy but works! I think in the long term FULL TEXT search is the way to go based on others comments.

Comment: this method seems to require knowing beforehand how many chords are in the text?

Comment: @pala_ From my tests no, seems to work without knowing the number of chords. I'll give the FULL TEXT option a go and compare performance. I think FULL TEXT will be better since it's built-in. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Try searching for 'fear by the side of the road' instead - it wont work. This only gets rid of the first chord - not all chords